# Setting up rDSN in IIS (if this is the right place)

Tags: iis-10

I have a couple of web sites and an hmailserver on my VPS.  I recently noticed that comcast, and I guess others, are rejecting email where there is no PTR or rDNS.  I can set up the PTR in DNS but not sure about the rDNS. I came across an old blog that shows how to do it in older versions of IIS but I'm not sure if this is the right way or how to do it in IIS-10

Say I have 3 domains
myDomain1.com and MyDomain2.com both use Ip x.x.x.y
and myMailServer.com uses Ip x.x.x.z

DNS for these are all set up on cloudflare.  MX records for the MyDomain1 and MyDomain2 both point to mail.MyMailserver.com.  I use hmailserver and all this works fine.

Comcast says I need a PTR record which I can set up on Cloudflare, and rDNS which is what I'm asking about.

This blog

http://www.expta.com/2010/01/how-to-enable-reverse-dns-lookup-in-iis.html

shows how to do it in earlier versions of IIS (I am on IIS-10) using IP Address and Domain Restrictions

So my questions are :

1 - if this is not the right way then please redirect me! else
2 - Do I use Allow Entry or Deny Entry?
3 - Do I use the mail domain x.x.x.z for all or the ip assigned in DNS - or both?
4 - do I do this for all domains?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to your VPS provider to check their control panel for the PTR/rDNS setup. Usually all the VPS providers has this functionality in their control panels. If not, then ask them to add a proper PTR record for your IP address pointed to your hostname.

The hostname itself should be with proper A record pointed to the IP address of your VPS server.

Separate PTR record setup should be created for all your IPs.

Comment: Thanks - I have a VPS but don't use the control panel, just manage the server directly.  years ago their first control panel wasn't that good and when they upgraded I just stayed with the basics, so I'd have to set it up myself in IIS or wherever it goes.  DNS A and MX records are all fine, I can add the PTR, just the rDNS I'm not sure about

Comment: I mean the control panel of your VPS provider, not a control panel installed on your server. If they don't have a reverse dns option, then just open them a ticket and they will assist you. As the IP address belongs to them, they are the only one who can create a PTR record for you, which will be resolved properly.

Comment: sorry for delay, I'll go back to them and see what they can do.  Thanks